# Форматирование текста в документации к Java методам/классам - отображение дженериков

Tags: java, документация, javadoc

## Дано:

Пытаюсь добаваить к описанию класса в конструкции

```
/**
*
*/
```

строку

`ArrayList<String>`

но отображается (как и тут, в цитате):

> ArrayList

## Пробовал эти варианты:

1. Экранирование

`ArrayList<\String>`

получилось:

> ArrayList\String>

2. Больше экранирования:

`ArrayList\<\String>`

получилось:

> ArrayList\ \String>

3. Оборачивание тегом `<code>`:

`<code>ArrayList<String></code>`

ничего не выходит:

> ArrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Старый метод: `ArrayList&lt;String&gt;`.

Современный поход (начиная с JDK 1.5): использовать теги `@literal` или `@code`.

*при этом надо обернуть тег и его содержимое фигурными скобками*

При использовании первого тега содержимое внутри не будет рассматриваться как HTML разметка (например, удобно для описания математических выражений). Второй тег используется для обертки кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
*  {@code ArrayList<String>} bla-bla-bla
*/
```

?